# Dynamic injection using @SpringBean in wicket

Tags: wicket

I have a form that based on collected information generates a report. I have multiple sources from which to generate reports, but the form for them is the same. I tried to implement strategy pattern using an interface implementing report generator services, but that led to wicket complaining about serialization issues of various parts of the report generator. I would like to solve this without duplicating the code contained in the form, but I have not been able to find information on dynamic injection with @SpringBean.

Here is a rough mock up of what I have

```java
public class ReportForm extends Panel {
    private IReportGenerator reportGenerator;
    
    public ReportForm(String id, IReportGenerator reportGenerator) {
        super(id);
        this.reportGenerator = reportGenerator;
        
        final Form<Void> form = new Form<Void>("form");
        this.add(form);

        ...

        form.add(new AjaxButton("button1") {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
            @Override
            protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target)
            {
                 byte[] report = reportGenerator.getReport(...);
                 ...
            }           
         });
    }
}
```

If I do it this way, wicket tries to serialize the concrete instance of reportGenerator. If I annotate the `reportGenerator` property with `@SpringBean` I receive `Concrete bean could not be received from the application context for class: IReportGenerator`

Edit: I have reworked implementations of IRerportGenerator to be able to annotate them with `@Component` and now I when I use `@SpringBean` annotation I get `More than one bean of type [IReportGenerator] found, you have to specify the name of the bean (@SpringBean(name="foo")) or (@Named("foo") if using @javax.inject classes) in order to resolve this conflict.` Which is exactly what I don't want to do.

Comment: Voting to close because you're asking multiple questions at once (why can't I inject Spring services in Wicket, and how should I design reporting sources), and your post lacks a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That said, I think you're going in the right direction by using a strategy pattern, but I suspect your Spring configuration is lacking a few settings to work well with Wicket. At the very least you should include your Spring configuration and the config you use to integrate it with Wicket.

Comment: Ok, I removed the followup question and will try to put together some example.

Comment: What I suspect is that you're missing configuration that makes Spring create serializable proxy classes for your services

Comment: The SpringBean annotation works without an issue where there is only a single implementation of an interface. However In this case I have multiple and I don't know how to specify which one to use dynamically. I am aware I can use the name withing SpringBean annotation, but that is hard coding it. What I am looking for is being able to specify which implementation to use during form instantiation. I was able to pass a concrete instance to the form, but since it was not proxied, wicket tried to serialize it and that is where I ran into the problem.

Comment: Ah I see. So what you're looking for is a qualifier-like mechanism that works in combination with Wicket. I think I can figure out a workaround that may work for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the behavior you're trying to achieve can be done with a slight workaround, by introducing a Spring bean that holds all IReportGenerator instances:

```java
@Component
public class ReportGeneratorHolder {
  private final List<IReportGenerator> reportGenerators;

  @Autowired
  public ReportGeneratorHolder(List<IReportGenerator> reportGenerators) {
    this.reportGenerators = reportGenerators;
  }

  public Optional<IReportGenerator> getReportGenerator(Class<? extends IReportGenerator> reportGeneratorClass) {
    return reportGenerators.stream()
                           .filter(reportGeneratorClass::isAssignableFrom)
                           .findAny();

  }
}
```

You can then inject this class into your Wicket page, and pass the desired class as a constructor-parameter. Depending on your Spring configuration you might need to introduce an interface for this as well.

```java
public class ReportForm extends Panel {
    @SpringBean
    private ReportGeneratorHolder reportGeneratorHolder;
    
    public ReportForm(String id, Class<? extends IReportGenerator> reportGeneratorClass) {
        super(id);

        IReportGenerator reportGenerator = reportGeneratorHolder
          .getReportGenerator(reportGeneratorClass)
          .orElseThrow(IllegalStateException::new);

        // Form logic omitted for brevity
    }
}
```

Comment: After figuring out what you meant by the "need to introduce an interface", this works, but now I am back to a serialization problem. Wicket tries to serialize the executor and fails.

Comment: By executor you mean the `IReportGenerator` instance you're retrieving from the holder? If it is assigned to a variable in (for instance) the main class and you're referring to it from within a nested class, then I believe it gets serialized along with the nested class. The solution in this case would be not to refer to the variable from within the inner class but call the holder method again

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am able to find, looking through documentation and even the source for wicket `@SpringBean` annotation, this isn't possible. The closest I got is with explicitly creating a proxy for a Spring bean based on class passed. As described in *13.2.4 Using proxies from the wicket-spring project* chapter in *Wicket in Action*.

```java
public class ReportForm extends Panel {
    private IReportGenerator reportGenerator;
    private Class<? extends IReportGenerator> classType;

    private static ISpringContextLocator CTX_LOCATOR = new ISpringContextLocator() {
        public ApplicationContext getSpringContext() {
            return ((MyApplication)MyApplication.get()).getApplicationContext();
        }
    };

    public ReportForm(String id, Class<? extends IReportGenerator> classType) {
        super(id);
        this.classType = classType;
        
        final Form<Void> form = new Form<Void>("form");
        this.add(form);

        ...

        form.add(new AjaxButton("button1") {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
            @Override
            protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target)
            {
                 byte[] report = getReportGenerator().getReport(...);
                 ...
            }           
         });
    }

    private <T> T createProxy(Class<T> classType) {
        return (T) LazyInitProxyFactory.createProxy(classType, new 
            SpringBeanLocator(classType, CTX_LOCATOR));
    }

    private IReportGenerator getReportGenerator() {
        if (reportGenerator = null) {
            reportGenerator = createProxy(classType);
        }
        return reportGenerator;
    }

}
```